# How to remove the filters in an interactive grid?

Tags: oracle-apex

I do not want the filters displayed when I open my webpage in another tab. But it should display the filtered data. How do I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try clear report cache by setting `clearCache` and / or `Request` fields of page URL. In `clearCache` put `CIR` for clearing report cache on target page. If target page contains more than one report, then all reports cache will be cleared. To clear specific report you have to put report static id in `Request` field (report static id can be set in `Advanced > Static ID` region attribute in Page Designer).

APEX URL syntax:
`f?p=App:Page:Session:Request:Debug:ClearCache:itemNames:itemValues:PrinterFriendly`

Example URL for Interactive Report:
`f?p=&APP_ID.:&APP_PAGE_ID.:&SESSION.:IR[report_static_id]::CIR::`

Example URL for Interactive Grid (since APEX 20.1):
`f?p=&APP_ID.:&APP_PAGE_ID.:&SESSION.:IG[report_static_id]::CIR::`

If you want to clear cache via page button, then in Link Builder set `Clear Cache` and / or `Request` fields.

Bear in mind, that clear cache will affect to the end of user session, so if you want to get your filters back, then you have to set them via URL.